Communication error between FE (client) and BE (server)
sorry for my English.
I have a backend service (net core) that I run on a server and an angular project that I start locally (with http server) and that connects to the server (I'm connected in VPN, therefore the same network).
strangely, the first api that I call from fe (login) is successful, the second, which determines which pages I can view based on the role, gives me the following error in the console:
"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): A : {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http: //10.7.2.242:5000/user/getPermission?page=/home","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://10.7.2.242:5000 /user/getPermission?page=/home: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}"
Followed by:
"GET http://10.7.2.242:5000/user/getPermission?page= /home net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".
If I edit by omitting the API, many of the subsequent ones give me the same error, others instead work correctly. No log is written, as if those bees are never called, which instead happens if I call them from postman or browser.
Obviously, I had previously tested both services locally and had no problems.
furthermore, I had tried to separate the frontend and backend on two different PCs connected to the same network, and in this case too everything worked correctly.
I don't think it's a Cors problem, otherwise I would have had the same problems trying with two PCs.
anyway, this is my code about it:
ConfigureServices:
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder =>
            {
                var allowedOrigin = Configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigin").Value;
                if (allowedOrigin == "*")
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                }
                else
                {
                    var allowedOrigins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(allowedOrigin);
                    builder.WithOrigins(allowedOrigins).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                }
            }));

Configure:
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins)
appsettings:
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AllowedOrigin": "*",


Use the Network tab in your browser's Developer tools (F12) to see what's actually sent to the server and inspect the response. There's no relevant JS or .NET code, so one can only guess. Perhaps something causes the entire server to crash. Perhaps a mistake in the JS code doesn't properly handle the server call. The message Uncaught (in promise) means the JS code isn't handling the exception and perhaps misses the actual response. We can't guess if you use await fetch() or then or something else

"ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" means the browser cannot reach the address. That's all it means. There is zero way to figure out why by examining the backend code. It's about as useful as asking "Here is the sink in my kitchen. Now, can you tell me why I can't walk through the front door?"

In the network tab:
Status 204 NO CONTENT
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Tue, 14 May 2024 13:34:02 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
OPTIONS /user/getPermission?page=/home HTTP/1.1
Accept: /
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 10.7.2.242:5000
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Preview and Response sections are empty.

I would add that the bees work correctly if called by the postman (same PC on which the frontend runs)

your server seems to be sending CORS headers, so a preflight is happening (postman doesn't have CORS rules so CORS is not an issue... no preflight ever).  I'd guess you are sending credentials with this fetch.  You can't wild-card origins when sending credentials... you might also need https.

exactly, in fact each API is associated with two records in the network tab. so I could solve it by inserting the client's network IP address into AllowedOrigin, instead of *? And would I have the option to enable all network IPs without using wildcards? Otherwise they would be constantly changing.

I tried but the result is the same

a confirmation, I tried to remove the sending of the token from the suspicious api. Without the token I don't encounter any problems, confirming that the problem is the one identified by browsermator

there's a reason modern browser have CORS rules.  If you were able to allow all origins, a malicious site could possibly send a credentialed request on behalf of the user.  (ex: `https://yoursite.com/change-password-and-email, along with payload ) The best thing to do is keep all requests same-site.  That way you don't need to set any CORS headers (which loosen CORS rules and make your site less secure)
